# Help in a proof in basic Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand this proof:

**Theorem**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine closed sets. If $f:X\to Y$ is a function such that $g\circ f\in k[X]$ for every $g\in K[Y]$, then $f$ is a morphism.

**Proof**

Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is a function such that $g\circ f\in k[X]$, whenever $g\in k[Y]$. We write $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ and take $g=s_i\in k[Y]$ the regular function corresponding to the polynomial $S_i\in k[S_1,\ldots S_m]$, then $s_i\circ f=f_i\in k[X]$ for each $i=a,\ldots,m$, showing $f$ is a morphism.

**Remark**

$k[X]$ is the coordinate ring of $X$.

**My doubts**

Why can we write $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$? Why $s_i\circ f=f_i\in k[X]$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been implicitly assumed that $f:X \subset \mathbb{A}^n \to Y\subset \mathbb{A}^m$ and note that $s_i$'s are just coordinate functions.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani yes, I know, but why $f$ can be write in components?

Comment: Any functions from an n-dimensional vector space to an m-dimensional vector space can be written in components. Because components are just the image of the projection to an element of a basis of the target space.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Thank you

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani speaking of the last question, I know that $s_i$'s are the coordinate functions, what I don't understand is why $g=s_i$.

Comment: Well, it's true for all $g$. So it's true for $s_i$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $f$ in components because $Y$ is a subset of $\mathbb K^m$. The monomial $S_i$ is just the projection onto the $i$th coordinate.

Comment: Then, every function in $K^m$ can be write in components. Why?

Comment: Because elements of $\mathbb K^m$ are $m$-tuples of elements of $\mathbb K$.